# How to root Huawei Ascend Y550?

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, huawei

I've been trying to root my Huawei Ascend Y550 but I had no luck since many of the rooting programs say "Rooting failed".  Is there a way to root this phone?  It is running Android 4.4.4 and the kernel is from September 29th, 2014.